# The type 'IpLoc option' does not contain a field 'ip'

Tags: f#

I have a function that return a record type, but the compiler complain:

```
The type 'IpLoc option' does not contain a field 'ip'
```

The function looks like:

```
let validIp (list : IpRanges list) (ip:string) : option<IpLoc> =
     list
        |> Seq.pick (fun e -> 
            let range = IPAddressRange.Parse(e.ipStartEnd);

            match range.Contains(IPAddress.Parse(ip)) with
            | true -> Some({ip=ip; subnet=e.subnet; gateway=e.gateway})
            | false -> None
        )
```

And the type is

```
type IpLoc =
     { ip : String
       subnet : String
       gateway : String }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the calling code. However from the error it looks like the calling code is trying to use the return value directly as an `IpLoc` instead of an `Option<IpLoc>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `Seq.pick` returns the first **value** where the provided function returns a **Some value**. See doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee353772(v=vs.100).aspx

For example:

```
let aseq = [ 'a'; 'b'; 'c' ]
let picked = aseq |> Seq.pick (fun e -> if e = 'b' then Some 42 else None)
> 
val picked : int = 42
```

So your `validIp` function returns the value of type `IpLoc` and not `Option<IpLoc>` as declared.

Change the type of your function or change returning value to the Option type or use `**Seq.tryPick**` function with similar signature that returns **Option value.**

Note that `Seq.pick` throws an exception (KeyNotFoundException) if there is no element in sequence where provided function returns **Some value**.

If you need to return `IpLoc`:

```
let validIp (list : IpRanges list) (ip:string) : IpLoc =
     list
        |> Seq.pick (fun e -> 
            let range = IPAddressRange.Parse(e.ipStartEnd);

            match range.Contains(IPAddress.Parse(ip)) with
            | true -> Some({ip=ip; subnet=e.subnet; gateway=e.gateway})
            | false -> None
        )
```

If you need to return `Option<IpLoc>`:

```
let validIpOption (list : IpRanges list) (ip:string) : Option<IpLoc> =
     list
        |> Seq.tryPick (fun e -> 
            let range = IPAddressRange.Parse(e.ipStartEnd);

            match range.Contains(IPAddress.Parse(ip)) with
            | true -> Some({ip=ip; subnet=e.subnet; gateway=e.gateway})
            | false -> None
        )
```

Comment: Do I understand in the right way, that seq.pick return the union type option?

Comment: In your function `Seq.pick` returns value of type `IpLoc`

Comment: Who do I have to put `Some` in front of return value. I made this sample to  `let val1 = seq{0 .. 10} |>
            Seq.pick( fun e ->
                        Some e)

printfn "%i" val1 `. Why  `Some e ` not `e` when I return only int.

Comment: This is how `Seq.pick` works. What value are you planning as the return type of `validIp`? `IpLoc` or `Option<IpLoc>` ?

Comment: I am trying to return `IpLoc`, what I am not understand is why to I have to write like this `Some({ip=ip; subnet=e.subnet; gateway=e.gateway})` not only `{ip=ip; subnet=e.subnet; gateway=e.gateway}`?

Comment: See documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee353772(v=vs.100).aspx "Seq.pick applies the given function to successive elements, returning the first value where the function returns a Some value." I'll edit the answer.